# How to show labels depending on the zoom scale and save it forever in one project?

Tags: qgis, scale, labeling

I have got a problem in showing labels for a polygon layer :

When I select "`Show labels`" in the layer's properties, then I select that I want to use the scaling to show or not my labels and I configure it.

Then everything works fine, I save and close my project.
When I reopen it, the labels are still visible, but the scale configuration doesn't work. They are showed at every scale.

Is there a way to keep this configuration even after closing the project ?

Comment: I forgot to inform that I am using QuantumGIS 1.7.3

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this bug in QGIS 1.7.4.

Instead of using the labeling tool from layer properties, I'd recommend using the new labeling function in label toolbar. (This will become the only option in QGIS 2.0.) It does not have this problem.

Comment: Hello, Ok I will try this with QGIS 1.7.4 as soon as possible. Many thanks for your answer.